# Glossy Heatmap Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

Is there a way to add a glossy finish to a heatmap using highcharts to make it look less 2 dimensional.

Here's an example of a type of heatmap I'd like the finish to be added on to:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/

I'm guessing that it would be an addition into:

```
plotOptions:{
   heatmap:{
      color: {}
   }
}
```

But in a heatmap the colors vary so I can't impose a common gradient on it.

Comment: 1) not as any sort of standard option 2) for what purpose? Those kind of effects are just distracting and goofy-looking to anyone needing to actually learn anything from the data

Comment: I mis-understood the question . One option is to use some textShadow kind of effect on datalabels

Comment: The purpose would be to make it look 3D. Shadowing doesn't make it look 3D, it just looks weird. The idea is to have it pop.

This would be more for an end user audience where data comprehension and nice finish would be equally important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change how color is calculated in the colorAxis, for example wrap `tweenColors` method and apply a gradient:

```
  (function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.ColorAxis.prototype, 'tweenColors', function(p, from, to, pos) {
      var ret = p.call(this, from, to, pos);

      return {
        radialGradient: {
          cx: 0.1,
          cy: 0.1,
          r: 0.7
        },
        stops: [
          [0, ret],
          [1, Highcharts.Color(ret).brighten(0.2).get('rgb')]
        ]
      }
    });
  })(Highcharts);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nkukv1g4/2/